# Basic shapes in poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am really having some problems finding a way to create a triangle in `poi` using `Shapes`. Is this not possible? From what i have read around, poi **should** be able to `draw basic shapes`... Is  `triangle` not one of them?

This example provided by poi does not help me to much...

```
    HSSFSimpleShape s = patriarch.createSimpleShape(a);
    s.setShapeType(HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_OVAL);
    s.setLineStyleColor(10,10,10);
    s.setFillColor(90,10,200);
    s.setLineWidth(HSSFShape.LINEWIDTH_ONE_PT * 3);
    s.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_DOTSYS);
```

Triangle is not one of the `HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_OVAL` variables. 
PS: i use **XSSF** classes

Comment: You say you're using XSSF, but all your code is HSSF, which is it?

Comment: its from examples from poi, as mentioned allready `This example provided by poi does not help me to much...` why not read  the entire questio...